# Image Intervention in Laravel using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, image

I have used this long time back before but never with Ajax, I cannot understand why it won't save the image as intended.
I have ensured it is there in config/app.php under providers and aliases. Also ensured it is installed and there in composer.json

My Controller:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

 public function store(Request $request)
{
   $files = $request->file('logo');
       
      // for save original image
      $ImageUpload = Image::make($files)->resize(100,100);
      $originalPath = './public/images/deliverypartners/';
      $ImageUpload->save($originalPath.time().$files->getClientOriginalName());
     

     $delivery_partner   =   DeliveryPartner::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id' => $request->id
        ],
        [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'logo'=> $request->logo,
            'priority' => $request->priority,
            'status' => $request->status,
        ] 
    ); 
           
    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

Ajax script

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('add-deliverypartner') }}",
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    name: name,
                    logo: logo,
                    priority: priority,
                    status: status,
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(res) {
                   
                    window.location.reload();
                    $("#btn-save").html('Submit');
                    $("#btn-save").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
```

I tried couple of other ways but none of it worked. Even used `$delivery_partner = new DeliveryPartner();` approach

When I remove

```
`$files = $request->file('logo');
           
          // for save original image
          $ImageUpload = Image::make($files)->resize(100,100);
          $originalPath = './public/images/deliverypartners/';
          $ImageUpload->save($originalPath.time().$files->getClientOriginalName());`
```

It saves the logo as filepath which is okay but why is Image Intervention not working?
I also made the folders in storage.

Comment: what have you done to debug the code?  Did you inspect the request on the Laravel side?  The error is because you need to provide Intervention Image with the full path where you want to save the file. Not a relative one.